# Flutter - FCM Remote/Silent Notification (app in background)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Flutter app that needs to receive FCM push messages (silent/background data message). I am not using Flutter's plugin for Firebase Cloud Messaging, as it does not support background mode currently. So I have integrated FCM IOS sdk into the project as per the Firebase documentation for IOS.

I can receive "notification" messages fine (where notification is shown to the user when a push message arrives). So I believe my setup (keys/fcm) is good.

The problem now is, when I send a data message (dont want the app to show a notification to the user), nothing happens.

My message looks like

```
{
  "to": "fcm-token",
  "content_available": true,
  "apns-priority": 5,
  "data": {
    "some_key": "some_value"
  }
}
```

I am expecting the data message above to trigger the following delegate method (but it does not).

```
override func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                              didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                              fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

I have tried enabling or disabling method swizzling but that didnt help either.

Following is how I setup delegate for FCM messaging

```
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                              didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                              fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void){
        print("didReceiveRemoteNotification")
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }
    
    func initFirebase(_ application: UIApplication) {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                         willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                         withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        completionHandler([[.alert, .sound]])
    }
    
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                         didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                         withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        print("withCompletionHandler")
        completionHandler()
    }
    
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError")
    }
    
    func application(application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        
        
        print("didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken")
    }
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("didReceiveRegistrationToken")
    }
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
            print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
}
```

Any idea why the delegates are not getting called for data messages???

P.S: Ofcourse I am testing on a real IOS device

Comment: Hi @N0000B, did you manage to solve your issue?

Comment: hi @N0000B did you solve this? im in the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't enable 'Remote notifications' in Background Modes in Singing & Capabilities.[image]